# Twilio whatsapp template with youtube thumbnail

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I am using a Twilio WhatsApp template to broadcast a message to the users and one of the placeholders in the template takes a youtube URL as input. A normal whatsapp message with youtube URL generates a youtube thumbnail on sending to the user. But in a twilio approved template with youtube URL, the thumbnail doesn't load when the message is sent. Is there way to keep the youtube thumbnail even for a twilio template?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is very little I can find in the WhatsApp API documentation on URLs in template messages. I did find these [WhatsApp template message guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/message-templates/guidelines) that say that:

> The URL domain in your links should belong to your business.

It's possible that WhatsApp will only show a URL preview in a template message if the URL domain is from your business.

You might find better answers asking in the [WhatsApp developer community channel](https://developers.facebook.com/community?sort=trending&category=766772797555412).